# C# Calculating with strings?

Tags: c#, int

I need help with this algorythm :

```
int num = this.UserID * 786;
this.ValidCode = num * 17;
num = this.ValidCode / 12;
this.ValidCode = num + 1991;
```

I found this code written in vb.net and converted it online to C# as I want to use this for some kind of licensing system.

It wont work because VS tells me i cant calculate with strings or cant convert int to string.

UserID is a string getting from a textbox .
I need a way to get it working to work with UserID variable got from textbox1 and textbox 2 should display the final result

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Error message is clear. You can't multiple with `string` and `int`. If `this.UserID` is suitable for an `int`, parse it with `Int32.Parse` or `Int32.TryParse`. And please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: He means that it looks like this.UserID is a string. Try and convert it to an int. Using Convert.ToInt32();

Answer (score 4):

You can't convert `string` to `int` implicitly, you need to use built-in function for that.

```
int num = Convert.ToInt32(this.UserID) * 786;
```

Comment: Thanks alot ! how can i now convert the final int value to a string ? EDIT : got it working with this :

Comment: @m1mk you need ToString(), but use google for things like that. You need to read some tutorial about basics in programming and basics in C#.

Answer (score -1):

```
int num = Convert.ToInt32(this.UserID) * 786;
this.ValidCode = num.ToString();
```